# Creating video from Frames in Android

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, mpeg-4

I am using Android MediaCodec : ExtractMpegFramesTest for grabbing frames from video but now i am not getting any useful information on google for How can i create video from frames.png in android?

Answer (score 1):

You can try INDE Media Pack - https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-inde-media-pack-for-android-tutorials

It has transcoding\remuxing functionality as MediaComposer class and several sample effects like JpegSubstituteEffect - it shows how substitute video frame by a picture from jpg file. You can take black video as a refefence and put images on it with a possibility to set duration, add audio track with help of audio effect etc.

[image]

Comment: Hi Marlon, please you let me know the steps how can i get JpegSubstituteEffect from  https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-inde-media-pack-for-android-tutorials

Comment: Samples are on github, you can get JpegSubstituteEffect here: https://github.com/INDExOS/media-for-mobile/blob/master/Android/samples/effects/src/com/intel/inde/mp/effects/JpegSubstituteEffect.java